# Password protected online database or spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, database

I have a client that wants a simple online database or spreadsheet solution.

## Requirements

- Custom fields and field types (text, images)
- CRUD contents through a web GUI
- Password protected (single user login)
- Search- and sortable fields (all)

## Not required

- Relations
- API

This isn't an enterprise solution. There's only ~700 records to add, even though they're fairly comprehensive. I'm about to suggest just using a Google Docs Spreadsheet, but are there any alternatives to consider? Also, can you make queries for a Google Docs Spreadsheet, similar to what you would to a DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been building an online database application over Google App Engine for such use-cases. It is called **[iFreeTools Creator](http://creator.ifreetools.com)**.

- Supports multiple data-types for fields including single-line text, multi-line text, numbers, images, geo-location and more.
- Forms and views are automatically generated for users based on their authorization profiles.
- Users would need nothing more than a Google / Google Apps / Yahoo! account to get started with the app.
- Custom Views can be created to segment the data using filtering criteria into multiple views. Keyword based search and client-side sorting is also available.

The client can use the free plan itself for the number of records you had specified. Email support is available even for the free users.

Comment: Thanks Raj. Looks like just what they need. I'll pass it along!